# Series convergence proof check

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I am doing a homework set that has a lot of problems similar to this one, and I want to make sure I am doing them right. The problem:

Given $\Sigma b_n\,$ converges and $0<b_n< 1/2,$ prove $\Sigma {b_n\over{1-b_n}}$ converges.

I attempt to solve using the direct comparison test. 
$${b_n\over{1-b_n}}\leq{b_n\over{1-{1\over2}}}=2b_n$$

And since $\Sigma b_n\,$ converges, $2\Sigma b_n\,$ converges. Therefore by the direct comparison test ${b_n\over{1-b_n}}$ converges.

Does my proof look correct? Any help appreciated.

Comment: Where your question?

Comment: Sorry, I edited the question. Looking for verification that my proof is correct.

Comment: Yes, your proof is correct.